# How can I use ChatGPT's API be used to enable voice assistant functionality for Discord calls in python libraries?

Tags: discord, discord.py, openai-api

I'm working on a Discord bot that can recognize specific voice commands during calls, like "Hey [bot's name], [questions]," convert them to text, and respond using the ChatGPT API with text-to-speech capabilities

even though with so many researching python libraries, I haven't been able to get this yet has anyone have any idea?

Comment: What is your question? What have you actually tried? If you are looking for recommendations on libraries, etc. then your question is off-topic - [ask]

Comment: Hi, I'm looking to integrate ChatGPT's API for voice command recognition during Discord calls.

I've been looking at various Python libraries but have been unable to find one that provides this functionality specifically.

Could you please guide me on how I can achieve this?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Guidance on what? You haven't shared any code and are asking multiple things in one question. Please check out the article I've on how to ask a question here on SO